# global function in jquery

Tags: jquery

i cant access to variable of ok in this code.
how to set this variable for global access

```
$('#Btn1').click(function(){
var ok=true;
});
$('#Btn2').click(function(){
 if ( ok ) alert('ok');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `var` and declare the variable in the outer scope instead:

```
var ok = false;
$('#Btn1').click(function() {
    ok = true;
});
$('#Btn2').click(function() {
    if(ok) alert('ok');
});
```

While removing `var` would be enough to make the variable global, it's much better to keep it local to the smallest possible scope - in this case that's the scope containing those two functions. Since you probably wrapped that code in a *document ready* callback function it will be that function's scope instead of the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

just declare ok  variable outside your handler

```
var ok=false;
$('#Btn1').click(function(){
  ok =true;
});
$('#Btn2').click(function(){
 if ( ok ) alert('ok');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To create global functions in JavaScript, you omit the var:

```
ok = true;
```

However, better style would be to declare the variable somewhere that is in scope for both functions, but in its own namespace, to avoid namespace pollution:

```
function () {
    var ok = false;
    $('#Btn1').click(function(){
        ok=true;
    });
    $('#Btn2').click(function(){
        if ( ok ) alert('ok');
    });
}
```

(Edit: formatting)

Answer (score 0):

While using a global variable will work fine, if your goal is just to know whether the first button was clicked or not, better (and more jQuery-ish) approach would be to store that data as part of the button itself, using the jQuery `.data()` method.

To make it even more flexible you can even save the number of times the button was clicked, then check that value when clicking the other button:

```
$('#Btn1').click(function(){
    $(this).data("click_count", (parseInt($(this).data("click_count")) || 0) + 1);
});

$('#Btn2').click(function(){
    var clickCount = (parseInt($('#Btn1').data("click_count")) || 0);
    if (clickCount > 0) {
        alert("clicked at least once");
    }
})​
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/aaWyC/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// this is a global variable
var isValidGlobal = false;

$(function() {
    // since this is global, i can alert it here
    alert(isValidGlobal);

    $('#Btn1').click(function() {
        // Set the global variable
        isValidGlobal = true;
        return false;
    });

    $('#Btn2').click(function() {

        if (isValidGlobal) alert('global variable');
        return false;
    });
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aaWyC/1/)**